# VB PictureBox and Web Browser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, picturebox

I currently have a picture box overlaying a web browser within my application I want the picture box to disappear when the website has loaded fully, is this possible? or do I need to simply add a timer to my Picture box with an average time it normally takes for the site to load, any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

No timer is needed.

Set webbrowser event:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    PictureBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the timer for?